# Tomcat webapp in a docker container does not run

Tags: docker

I am very new to docker.

I am trying to run my web app inside a docker container.

Below is my docker file

```
    FROM tomcat:8.0-alpine
LABEL maintainer="saurav.sarkar1@gmail.com"

COPY target/chemistry-opencmis-server-fileshare-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/cmisfileshare.war

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

When i run my container.

Tomcat starts properly and the war file is copied and extracted properly under webapps.

However if i navigate to localhost:80/cmisfileshare i get 404.

Comment: What is the command you use to start it running?

Comment: running the catalina.sh

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the java version mismatch.

I logged into the container and checked the logs. It was throwing java version mismatch error.

It was due to the base image i was using which was using Java 7.

I changed it to FROM tomcat:8.0-jre8 and it worked.